# CUDA: Is it safe to apply `+=` in parallel to elements of an array located on the device?

Tags: c, cuda

I noticed strange (incorrect) behavior after compiling and executing a CUDA script, and was able to isolate it to the following minimal example. First I define an export-to-CSV function for integer arrays (just for debugging convenience):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    
void int1DExportCSV(int *ptr, int n){
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("1D IntOutput.CSV", "w");
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        fprintf(f, "%i,", ptr[i]);
    }
    fprintf(f, "%i", ptr[n-1]);
}
```

Then I defined a kernel function which increases a certain element of an input array by one:

```
__global__ void kernel(int *ptr){
    int x = blockIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y;
    int offset = x + gridDim.x * y;
    ptr[offset] += 1;
}
```

The main loop allocates a vector of one's called `a`, allocates an empty array `b`, and allocates a device copy of `a` called `dev_a`:

```
#define DIM 64
int main(void){
    int *a;
    a = (int*)malloc(DIM*DIM*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < DIM*DIM; i++){
        a[i] = 0;
    }
    int *b;
    b = (int*)malloc(DIM*DIM*sizeof(int));
    int *dev_a;
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_a, sizeof(int)*DIM*DIM );
    cudaMemcpy( dev_a, a, DIM*DIM*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
```

Then I feed `dev_a` into a DIM-by-DIM-by-DIM grid of blocks, each with DIM threads, copy the results back, and export them to CSV:

```
    dim3 blocks(DIM,DIM,DIM);
    kernel<<<blocks,DIM>>>(dev_a);
    cudaMemcpy( b, dev_a, sizeof(int)*DIM*DIM, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    int1DExportCSV(b, DIM*DIM);
}
```

The resulting CSV file is DIM*DIM in length, and is filled with DIM's. However, while the length is correct, it should be filled with DIM*DIM's, since I am essentially launching a DIM*DIM*DIM*DIM hypercube of threads, in which the last two dimensions are all devoted to incrementing a unique element of the device array `dev_a` by one.

My first reaction was to suspect that the `ptr[offset] += 1` step might be a culprit, since multiple threads are potentially executing this step at the exact same time, and so each thread might be updating an old copy of ptr while unaware that there are a bunch of other threads doing it at the same time. However, I don't know enough about the "taboo's of CUDA" to tell if this is a reasonable guess or not.

Hardware problems are (to the best of my knowledge) not an issue; I am using a GTX560 Ti, so launching a 3-dimensional grid of blocks is allowed, and my thread count per block is 64, well below the maximum of 1024 imposed by the Fermi architecture.

Am I making a simple mistake? Or is there a subtle error in my example?

Additionally, I noticed that when I increase DIM to 256, the resulting array appears to be filled with random integers between 290 to 430! I am completely baffled by this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not safe.  The threads in a block are stepping on each other.

Your threads in each threadblock are all updating the *same location* in memory:

```
ptr[offset] += 1;
```

`offset` is the same for every thread in the block:

```
int x = blockIdx.x;
int y = blockIdx.y;
int offset = x + gridDim.x * y;
```

That is a no-no.  The results are undefined.
Instead use [atomics](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions):

```
atomicAdd(ptr+offset, 1);
```

or a [parallel reduction](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) method of some sort.

Comment: Aha, so it *was* the threads updating the same object simultaneously that caused the problem, thanks! I hadn't read up to the "atomic operations" section of the text I'm using yet, but I guess I'll do that now.

Comment: added a doc link for atomics in the CUDA programming guide, for reference